# Using the elements of a seq/coll as call/recur arguments

Tags: clojure

I'm encountered with this situation:

```
(fn produce [] '(val0 val1))

;...

(loop [
    arg0 false
    arg1 false
    arg2 false] 

    ;...

)
```

Is there some sort of unpack function/macro such that you could call

```
(recur (unpack (produce)) :arg2)
```

within the loop context? I'm aware that I could just do something like

```
(recur (nth (produce) 0) (nth (produce) 1) :arg2)
```

but surely the former solution would be more elegant?

IIRC Common Lisp code can return more than one value, can Clojure too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apply-recur macro in Clojure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670010/apply-recur-macro-in-clojure)

Comment: I think the idiomatic way to return multiple values in Clojure is to wrap them in a `vector`. But there is no equivalent to CL's `values` form which allows the caller to decide to either handle one return value, or multiple return values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe destructuring in the `loop` bindings themselves will help?

```
(loop [ [arg0 arg1] [false false] arg2 false] ...
```

lets you `(recur (produce) arg2)` in the loop body, with the 2-element sequence returned by `produce` destructured and bound to `arg0` and `arg1`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, destructuring works well and will do what you want.  The one issue with doing something like

```
(loop [[arg0 arg1] (get-my-arg-list)] ...
```

is that you have to bundle everything back up into a list when you call `recur`.  Because of this, the recursive calls will look like

```
(recur [new-arg0 new-arg1])
```

If this is a deal breaker, you can also define an anonymous function to use with `recur` and then use `apply` to unpack the argument list when you call it the first time, though this technique is rather ugly overall.  Ex:

```
(apply (fn [arg0 arg1]
         ...
         (recur new-arg0 new-arg1))
       (get-my-arg-list))
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but that `recur` seems to call the fn rather the loop...?

Comment: Exactly.  The effect is the same (you still get tail recursion), but since you have a fully fledged function object, you can use apply.  This technique is probably a net negative overall (loop is generally much prettier), but if you want to avoid wrapping arguments in lists or unpacking the initial list yourself, this will allow you to do so.