# Recursive/nested with "rest" parameters

Tags: clojure

I frequently want to build up maps with all the keys, but don't want the keys to show up if their values are nil. So:

```
(building-map :a 1 :b nil :c 3 :d nil :e 5)
```

would yield {:a 1 :c 3 :e 5}. (Obviously I don't know the values in advance, but it's convenient for purposes of demonstration to hard code it.) I decided to build my own assoc-type function that ignored nils, called "asif":

```
(defn asif [m & kvs]
  (if (empty? kvs)
  m
    (if (second kvs)
      (recur (assoc m (first kvs) (second kvs)) (drop 2 kvs))
      (recur m (drop 2 kvs)))))
```

(I started by looking at *assoc*, so I am aware that this what they call a "naive" implementation. But run with it for now.) Now, of course, because I am greedy, I want it to work recursively:

```
(asif {} :a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d nil :e {:sub1 1 :sub2 nil :a 1})
```

This should return {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :e {:sub1 1 :a 1}}. But it won't of course, because it just sees the map on "e" as a single value.

My solution, currently, is to do this:

```
(asif {} :a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d nil :e (asif {} :sub1 1 :sub2 nil :a 1))
```

which works, and is fine, but this situation of "I've collected parms with &" and now want to recurse on them, but I can't, has always sort of bugged me. I know I can:

- Pass in the whole map to begin with instead of using &.
- Write a macro

But is there anyway to do this using &? (I've monkeyed with "apply" among other approaches.) Or is it that by the time you've collected the parms with &, the die is cast?

UPDATE: Just to clarify, this isn't really about removing nils—is't about using rest parameters (hence the subject title). It's just a question I run into periodically and (in this particular instance) I happened to run into it again today when thinking on "could I use [& rest] to write an assoc analogue that ignored nil values recursively"?

Comment: Have you considered an approach where you build maps using the regular functions and then have a function that prunes map entries with nil values recursively?

Comment: Yeah, that was my first bulleted point "pass in the whole map". And what I have works fine. I'm more interested about whether the & can actually be pressed into service here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem, I think, is that there's a mismatch between what you are doing in the top level call and then in the recursive calls. In the top level call, you have a map and multiple key/value pairs, but in the recursive call you just have a map, so you're not really `assoc`ing anymore, you are removing nils from an existing map.

So I would say that since you're doing two different things, you need two different functions.

Here's a fairly simple way to recursively remove the nils from nested maps:

```
(defn recursively-prune-nils [m]
  (into {} (map (fn [[k v :as pair]] 
                  [k
                   (if (map? v)
                     (recursively-prune-nils v)
                     v)])
                (filter second m))))
```

We can't use `recur` here because it wouldn't be in tail position, so this would eventually blow up if the maps are very deeply nested.

You could then use that inside your `asif` function:

```
(defn asif [m & kvs]
        (if (empty? kvs)
          m
          (if (second kvs)
            (if (map? (second kvs))
              (recur (assoc m (first kvs) (recursively-prune-nils (second kvs))) (drop 2 kvs))
              (recur (assoc m (first kvs) (second kvs)) (drop 2 kvs)))
            (recur m (drop 2 kvs)))))
```

This seems to do what you want:

```
user> (asif {} :a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d nil :e {:sub1 1 :sub2 nil :a 1})
{:a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :e {:sub1 1, :a 1}}
```

Comment: OK, what if instead of ...:e being a map, it were a vector? like :e [:sub1 1 :sub2 nil :a 1]? I think I'm still stuck, because the &rest collects things into a vector and passing a vector isn't the same. At least I don't think apply would work here.

Comment: I'd never run into this before, but `recur` won't work with `apply`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3670521/365064
You could still recursively call `asif` though. You have another problem though, which is that to write `(apply asif...)` on  `:e`, at that point you don't have a map to `assoc` to. 
At that point, you could have different arities of `asif`... but this seems like a lot of extra complexity. And I think that semantically, with a submap, you're really not `assoc`ing anymore so it doesn't make sense to try to handle the two cases with the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it (written as a unit test).  Basically, don't reinvent the wheel unless you really, really need to.  Just use `postwalk` instead.

```
The code:

(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.walk :as walk]
    [schema.core :as s]
    [tupelo.schema :as tsk]
  ))

(def kv-data [:a 1 :b nil :c 3 :d nil :e {:x 1 :y nil :z 1}])

(s/defn map-remove-nil-vals :- tsk/Map
  [map-in :- tsk/Map]
  (reduce-kv
    (fn [accum k v]
      (if (nil? v)
        accum
        (assoc accum k v)))
    {}
    map-in))

(defn walk-drop-mapentry-nil-vals
  [arg]
  (walk/postwalk (fn [item]
                   (if (map? item)
                     (map-remove-nil-vals item)
                     item))
    arg))

(dotest
  (let [map-data (apply hash-map kv-data)
        result   (walk-drop-mapentry-nil-vals map-data)]
    (is= (spyx-pretty result)
      {:e {:x 1, :z 1}, :c 3, :a 1}
      )))
```

and the result:

```
Testing _bootstrap

-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 13
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

result => {:e {:x 1, :z 1}, :c 3, :a 1}

Ran 2 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.

Passed all tests
```

Comment: Hey, Alan, that's a very nice example, but the question isn't really about how to remove the nils, it's about whether it's possible to use [& rest] parameters in a recursive fashion as described. I mean, the answer may just be "no".